# font awesome icons not showing in IE10

Tags: html, css, apache

I'm having an issue with font awesome icons. Nothing is showing on IE10. They work in all other browsers. If I go to the font awesome website I can see them, so I know its not my security settings. I'm serving fa from my directory.

heres my header from font-awesome.css

```
**Key**                        **Value**
Response                   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date                       Wed, 23 Mar 2016 20:19:23 GMT
Server                     Apache
Strict-Transport-Security  max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Last-Modified              Thu, 25 Feb 2016 21:08:44 GMT
Accept-Ranges              bytes
X-Frame-Options            SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control              max-age=600
Keep-Alive                 timeout=5, max=99
Connection                 Keep-Alive
Content-Type               text/css
Content-Length             6,588
```

here's my htaccess

```
     <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
         </IfModule>
     </FilesMatch>

# webfont mime types
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

    # webfonts and svg:
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Does it work when included from a CDN? Does your console output anything?

Comment: It doesn't work with a CDN via HTTPS or HTTP. The CSS file is showing a 200 response or 304 of its cached.

Comment: My google fonts aren't working either if that means anything. I can do without those, really need the icons though.